# When does Javascript "initialize" a RegEx pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I take care to declare a RegEx pattern once and reuse if possible, for performance reasons. I'm not entirely certain why - something I probably read once many years ago and has been filed away in the ol' skull sponge.

I find myself in a regex-heavy situation, and a thought occurred... does declaring a RegEx pattern "instantiate" or "initialize" that pattern, or does it just store the pattern until it's needed?

```
var NonNumbers = /[^0-9]/g; //"initialized" here?
"h5u4i15h1iu".replace(NonNumbers, "*"); //or "initialized" here?
```

Maybe `RegExp()` actually creates one and the literal waits until it's used, even though both patterns return the same results?

```
var NonNumbers = /[^0-9]/g; //just stores the pattern
var NonNumbers = RegExp(/[^0-9]/, 'g'); //actually creates the RegExp
```

Just an itch I'm hoping someone who understands the inner workings can scratch.

Comment: on declaration, so re-using named vars instead of hard-coding literals will improve perf.

Comment: In case if you are using `.exec` there will be a difference, because when using `.exec` the regex stores an index from which it will start at next call.

Comment: Literal is just syntactic sugar, right? They're both `RegExp` objects.

Comment: Side note: `/[^0-9]/` is equivalent to `/\D/`

Comment: @KennethK. Yes. But the question is: _whether he should create a regex every time he's in need for one, or he could just store it in a variable and reuse it over and over again?_

Comment: When it encounters the statement  `var Rx = /[^0-9]/;` it creates a regex instance. I think, but not sure, something like `string.replace(/[^0-9]/, "");` creates a new object on the stack each time.

Comment: @sln I know for certain the latter does create a new instance every time (holding some voodoo on the browser implementation), but it's whether or not that first one creates it instantly or is simply a placeholder that I was interested in

Comment: @RandyHall I believe it creates it.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I hold the same belief. But belief is not always reality, so I'm hoping there's some documented authoritative answer I was unable find on my own

Comment: I believe that within a script's life, the variables are created when encountered. If an object is created in global scope and never re-assigned, it is only created once, no matter how many times it is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Mozilla spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> You construct a regular expression in one of two ways:
>
> Using a regular expression literal, which consists of a pattern enclosed between slashes, as follows:
>
> ```
> var re = /ab+c/;
> ```
>
> Regular expression literals provide compilation of the regular expression *when the script is loaded*. If the regular expression remains constant, using this can improve performance.
>
> Or calling the constructor function of the RegExp object, as follows:
>
> ```
> var re = new RegExp('ab+c');
> ```
>
> Using the constructor function provides *runtime compilation* of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

Since the spec indicates that the regular expression is being compiled when using the literal syntax, it is also safe to assume that it is being initialized as a full, bona-fide regular expression object at that point.

Another advantage of using literals is that regular expressions can be interned, meaning that if the same regular expression literal is found in multiple places, both literals can refer to the same object, saving both memory and initialization costs.